# Using routes to link to home/subpage/THIS instead of home/THIS

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just want to link to "/resources/entrepreneurship" instead of "/entrepreneurship". The code below doesn't seem to work because I don't know how to link to it properly.

**routes.rb**

```
Project::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  get '/about',    to: 'static_pages#about'
  get '/resources/entrepreneurship', to: 'static_pages#entrepreneurship'
end
```

**Header**

```
<li><%= link_to "Entrepreneurship", resources/entrepreneurship_path %></li>
```

The error is this when I try to open the page. 
"undefined local variable or method `resources' for #<#:0x007fd46571a160>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for invoking a matched route involves substituting `_` for `/` when specifying the path in your link tag:

```
<%= link_to "Entrepreneurship", resources_entrepreneurship_path %>
```

Note a few things:

First, you can specify a name for your route that will override the default name:

```
# config/routes.rb
get '/resources/entrepreneurship', to: 'static_pages#entrepreneurship', :as 'custom_name'

# view template
<%= link_to "Entrepreneurship", custom_name_path %>
```

Second, `routes.rb` assumes that paths are relative to the application root, so you can omit the preceding `/` in your route declaration and it will still resolve correctly:

```
# config/routes.rb
get 'resources/entrepreneurship', to: 'static_pages#entrepreneurship'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `resources_entrepreneurship_path`. Note the `_` instead of the `/`.

Also, you can nest routes inside a namespace like this:

```
namespace 'resources' do
    get 'entrepreneurship', to: 'static_pages#entrepreneurship'
end
```